# How to make regex to match this?

Tags: regex

I want to match the highlighted section.

[image]

The main challenge is with the newline characters I guess.
I know that I could just do some "git tricks" to keep all the "head" versions, but I want to know how to do this with regex (challenge with newline characters)

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        this.foo(bar);
=======
        baz.qux.Quux = corge;
        grault.garlply(waldo);
        Fred = new plugh();
>>>>>>> origin/georgiana-9
```

Comment: Well, `==.*` matches the highlighted section, but I assume that's not what you want. I suggest you make specific criteria to match and show what you already tried. You also need to specify a language tag.

Comment: it would be good if you pasted the actual code. Anyway, you can do it by typing the wanted string and when there's a new line just add `\n`

Comment: You can try `==[\S\s]+`

Comment: @krisiliev I pasted a sample code

Comment: @sln Thanks, that really helped! One more thing: I modified yours to

==[\S\s]+georgiana\-9

So that it will not match anything else after georgiana-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might use something like this:

`===.(.*\n)+?>>>.*` , assuming that your example is spot on as a requirement.  If you're new to regex, [regexr](http://regexr.com) is a good resource for regex testing.

Comment: Might want to make that non-greedy `===.(.*\n)+?>>>.*` or it will match more than one instance.

Comment: That's a good one. @sln 's solution is also okay. Here is mine where I removed all the "unnecessary" parts:
=(.*\n)+>>>>>>> origin\/georgiana\-9

Answer (score 0):

[image]In vim (macVim 7.3), the following search pattern does the job:

```
/^==*\n\(.*\n\)* 

/ -> find
 ^= -> line starting with =
   =* -> there could be more  = sign afterwards
     \n -> followed by a new line
       \(.*\n\)* -> any number of lines afterwards
```